# How to pass web proxy address to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext.UserHeaders?

Tags: azure, http-headers, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, http-proxy

I am writing some C# code that uses the Azure Resource Manager APIs and my CloudBlobClient needs to use a web proxy. According to the documentation for OperationContext.UserHeaders property at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.operationcontext.userheaders.aspx, UserHeaders can be used to specify a proxy. Can you please share how this should be done properly?

Edited after Gaurav Mantri's comment.

The Azure clients below allow you to specify a proxy to be used via the httpClientHandler but the CloudBlobClient does not respect the proxy information from StorageManagementClient and there doesn't seem to be a way to pass the proxy information to the CloudBlobClient. Our users may want to specify different proxies for multiple connections and it doesn't seem the current architecture will easily allow this.

//Example code that instantiates clients with proxy information inside the httpClientHandler

```
armCompute = new ComputeManagementClient(tokenCredentials, httpClientHandler)
armStorage = new StorageManagementClient(tokenCredentials, httpClientHandler)
armNetwork = new NetworkManagementClient(tokenCredentials, httpClientHandler)
armResource = new ResourceManagementClient(tokenCredentials, httpClientHandler)
armSubscription = new SubscriptionClient(tokenCredentials, httpClientHandler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're understanding it incorrectly. The [`documentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.operationcontext.userheaders.aspx) states:

> Gets or sets additional headers on the request, for example, for proxy
>   or logging information.

From what I understand you use this to get or set the headers for your proxy to understand and not specify proxy configuration settings.

In order to specify proxy settings, you would need to specify those in your application configuration file (web.config or app.config).

Comment: You are correct. This is a limitation of the APIs that doesn't allow supporting multiple proxies for multiple connections. I would like to be able to specify the proxy details for blob clients in the same way I do for the other clients mentioned above. This would offer more flexibility in our application by allow admins to choose different proxies based on the region in which they are deploying.